# Adding a query (new join) to an existing join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I have three databases (all on one server) that I need to join tables on. Essentially I do a join across two tables to determine the identification of particular users who do a certain thing after a certain date. It works fine:

```
SELECT a.THING, a.ANOTHERTHING, b.IDENTIFICATION, b.RELEVANTDATE
FROM FIRSTDATABASE.TABLE a
JOIN SECONDDATABASE.TABLE b
ON a.THING = b.THING
WHERE ANOTHERTHING = '----' AND IDENTIFICATION <> 'NULL'
AND b.RELEVANTDATE > date('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

At present I'm also running a second query by its lonesome - this is one table, on a third database - to get all users with a certain amount of an item. It also works:

```
SELECT ITEM, AMOUNT, IDENTIFICATION
FROM TABLE
WHERE ITEM = '----' AND AMOUNT > '0' AND IDENTIFICATION <> 'NULL'
GROUP BY AMOUNT
```

I then, using the first table as my guide, use VLOOKUP so I can get the AMOUNT generated in the second query for each and every user IDENTIFICATION meeting the criteria after a certain date AND who did a certain thing, from the first query.

My question is, how would I join these two into one large query?

Comment: Add fields from the third table to the select clause.  Add the third table to the from clause, joining on the appropriate field.  Adjust the rest of the where clause as required.

Comment: What are you matching the second query on?  IDENTIFICATION?  Do you want a SUM of matching records, or will there be only one?

Comment: So let's use the example of chocolate bars. In the first query I want to get the unique ID of all customers who logged in after a certain date and did "something" In the second query i'm getting the amount of chocolate bars owned by each ID. Then - the way I'm doing it now - I do a VLOOKUP to determine, after a certain date, what specific customers did something and how many chocolate bars each owns. I'd like to get back the unique ID and the number of chocolate bars each had who did something and after a certain date.